Why booting linux kernel fails when using busybox filesystem
I am trying to boot the linux kernel on beagle bone black board.
I am providing the root filesystem as an archive.
I get this archive by compiling busybox, then gzip the output directory, then use cpio to archive, and finally use mkimage to add the u-boot header.
~/busybox$ find . | cpio -o > initramfs
~/busybox$ cat initramfs | gzip > initramfs.gz
~/busybox$ mkimage -A arm -O linux -T ramdisk -a 0x88080000 -d initramfs.gz ../tftp/initramfs

The booting stucks as follows:
    TFTP from server 192.168.7.1; our IP address is 192.168.7.2
Filename 'uImage'.
Load address: 0x82000000
Loading: #################################################################
         #################################################################
         #################################################################
         #################################################################
         ##################################
         7.3 MiB/s
done
Bytes transferred = 4310624 (41c660 hex)
link up on port 0, speed 100, full duplex
Using cpsw device
TFTP from server 192.168.7.1; our IP address is 192.168.7.2
Filename 'am335x-boneblack.dtb'.
Load address: 0x88000000
Loading: ##
         3.9 MiB/s
done
Bytes transferred = 24428 (5f6c hex)
link up on port 0, speed 100, full duplex
Using cpsw device
TFTP from server 192.168.7.1; our IP address is 192.168.7.2
Filename 'initramfs'.
Load address: 0x88080000
Loading: #################################################################
         #################################################################
         #################################################################
         #################################################################
         #################################################################
         #################################################################
         #########################################################
         7.4 MiB/s
done
Bytes transferred = 6559765 (641815 hex)
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 82000000 ...
   Image Name:   Angstrom/3.8.13/beaglebone
   Created:      2013-07-30   9:56:26 UTC
   Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
   Data Size:    4310560 Bytes = 4.1 MiB
   Load Address: 80008000
   Entry Point:  80008000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
## Loading init Ramdisk from Legacy Image at 88080000 ...
   Image Name:   
   Created:      2024-08-03  22:14:30 UTC
   Image Type:   ARM Linux RAMDisk Image (gzip compressed)
   Data Size:    6559701 Bytes = 6.3 MiB
   Load Address: 88080000
   Entry Point:  88080000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 88000000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x88000000
   Loading Kernel Image ... OK
   Loading Ramdisk to 8f9be000, end 8ffff7d5 ... OK
   Loading Device Tree to 8f9b5000, end 8f9bdf6b ... OK

Starting kernel ...

Uncompressing Linux... done, booting the kernel.
[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[    0.000000] Linux version 3.8.13 (koen@rrMBP) (gcc version 4.7.3 20130205 (prerelease) (Linaro GCC 43
[    0.000000] CPU: ARMv7 Processor [413fc082] revision 2 (ARMv7), cr=50c5387d
[    0.000000] CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT aliasing instruction cache
[    0.000000] Machine: Generic AM33XX (Flattened Device Tree), model: TI AM335x BeagleBone
[    0.000000] Memory policy: ECC disabled, Data cache writeback
[    0.000000] AM335X ES1.0 (neon )
[    0.000000] PERCPU: Embedded 8 pages/cpu @c0b07000 s9408 r8192 d15168 u32768
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 129792
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: console=ttyO0,115200n8 root=/dev/ram0 rw initrd=0x88080000
[    0.000000] PID hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
[    0.000000] __ex_table already sorted, skipping sort
[    0.000000] allocated 1048576 bytes of page_cgroup
[    0.000000] please try 'cgroup_disable=memory' option if you don't want memory cgroups
[    0.000000] Memory: 511MB = 511MB total
[    0.000000] Memory: 504076k/504076k available, 20212k reserved, 0K highmem
[    0.000000] Virtual kernel memory layout:
[    0.000000]     vector  : 0xffff0000 - 0xffff1000   (   4 kB)
[    0.000000]     fixmap  : 0xfff00000 - 0xfffe0000   ( 896 kB)
[    0.000000]     vmalloc : 0xe0800000 - 0xff000000   ( 488 MB)
[    0.000000]     lowmem  : 0xc0000000 - 0xe0000000   ( 512 MB)
[    0.000000]     pkmap   : 0xbfe00000 - 0xc0000000   (   2 MB)
[    0.000000]     modules : 0xbf800000 - 0xbfe00000   (   6 MB)
[    0.000000]       .text : 0xc0008000 - 0xc05e9e60   (6024 kB)
[    0.000000]       .init : 0xc05ea000 - 0xc062b4c0   ( 262 kB)
[    0.000000]       .data : 0xc062c000 - 0xc069e460   ( 458 kB)
[    0.000000]        .bss : 0xc069e460 - 0xc06f7efc   ( 359 kB)
[    0.000000] Hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000]  RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=4 to nr_cpu_ids=1.
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS:16 nr_irqs:16 16
[    0.000000] IRQ: Found an INTC at 0xfa200000 (revision 5.0) with 128 interrupts
[    0.000000] Total of 128 interrupts on 1 active controller
[    0.000000] OMAP clockevent source: GPTIMER1 at 24000000 Hz
[    0.000000] sched_clock: 32 bits at 24MHz, resolution 41ns, wraps every 178956ms
[    0.000000] OMAP clocksource: GPTIMER2 at 24000000 Hz
[    0.000000] Console: colour dummy device 80x30
[    0.000232] Calibrating delay loop... 993.47 BogoMIPS (lpj=969728)
[    0.029175] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.029319] Security Framework initialized
[    0.029378] Mount-cache hash table entries: 512
[    0.035274] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
[    0.035298] Initializing cgroup subsys memory
[    0.035338] Initializing cgroup subsys blkio
[    0.035432] CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
[    0.035816] CPU0: thread -1, cpu 0, socket -1, mpidr 0
[    0.035869] Setting up static identity map for 0x803787c0 - 0x8037880c
[    0.036699] Brought up 1 CPUs
[    0.036713] SMP: Total of 1 processors activated (993.47 BogoMIPS).
[    0.037545] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.046314] omap_hwmod: wd_timer2: _wait_target_disable failed
[    0.085695] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
[    0.085853] rstctl core: initialized rstctl subsystem
[    0.086164] regulator-dummy: no parameters
[    0.086484] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.086970] DMA: preallocated 256 KiB pool for atomic coherent allocations
[    0.092527] pinctrl-single 44e10800.pinmux: 142 pins at pa f9e10800 size 568
[    0.092990] platform 49000000.edma: alias fck already exists
[    0.093010] platform 49000000.edma: alias fck already exists
[    0.093025] platform 49000000.edma: alias fck already exists
[    0.093845] OMAP GPIO hardware version 0.1
[    0.096497] gpio-rctrl rstctl.3: loaded OK
[    0.099798] hw-breakpoint: debug architecture 0x4 unsupported.
[    0.101074] cpsw.0: No hwaddr in dt. Using 64:8c:bb:79:96:36 from efuse
[    0.101095] cpsw.1: No hwaddr in dt. Using 64:8c:bb:79:96:38 from efuse
[    0.109406] bio: create slab <bio-0> at 0
[    0.116287] edma-dma-engine edma-dma-engine.0: TI EDMA DMA engine driver
[    0.116580] vmmcsd_fixed: 3300 mV 
[    0.118312] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.118569] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.118634] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.118828] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.120128] omap_i2c 44e0b000.i2c: bus 0 rev0.11 at 400 kHz
[    0.121123] input: tps65217_pwr_but as /devices/ocp.2/44e0b000.i2c/i2c-0/0-0024/input/input0
[    0.122379] DCDC1: at 1500 mV 
[    0.123232] vdd_mpu: 925 <--> 1325 mV at 1325 mV 
[    0.124074] vdd_core: 925 <--> 1150 mV at 1100 mV 
[    0.124927] LDO1: at 1800 mV 
[    0.125741] LDO2: at 3300 mV 
[    0.127282] LDO3: 1800 mV 
[    0.128120] LDO4: at 3300 mV 
[    0.128851] tps65217 0-0024: TPS65217 ID 0xe version 1.2
[    0.129304] omap_i2c 44e0b000.i2c: unable to select pin group
[    0.129789] omap_i2c 4819c000.i2c: bus 1 rev0.11 at 100 kHz
[    0.131221] omap_i2c 4819c000.i2c: unable to select pin group
[    0.131367] media: Linux media interface: v0.10
[    0.131427] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[    0.131526] pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
[    0.131536] pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
[    0.131950] Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Initialized.
[    0.132786] Switching to clocksource gp_timer
[    0.143197] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    0.143816] TCP established hash table entries: 4096 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
[    0.143898] TCP bind hash table entries: 4096 (order: 4, 81920 bytes)
[    0.143988] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 4096 bind 4096)
[    0.144049] TCP: reno registered
[    0.144066] UDP hash table entries: 256 (order: 1, 12288 bytes)
[    0.144091] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 256 (order: 1, 12288 bytes)
[    0.144338] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    0.144782] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[    0.144795] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[    0.144803] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[    0.144812] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[    0.145049] Trying to unpack rootfs image as initramfs...
[    0.147796] rootfs image is not initramfs (no cpio magic); looks like an initrd
[    0.178927] Freeing initrd memory: 6404K
[    0.179437] CPU PMU: probing PMU on CPU 0
[    0.179460] hw perfevents: enabled with ARMv7 Cortex-A8 PMU driver, 5 counters available
[    0.179917] omap2_mbox_probe: platform not supported
[    0.182409] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.5.2
[    0.182549] Dquot-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.183269] NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type
[    0.183337] Key type id_resolver registered
[    0.183347] Key type id_legacy registered
[    0.183388] jffs2: version 2.2. (NAND) (SUMMARY)  © 2001-2006 Red Hat, Inc.
[    0.183724] msgmni has been set to 997
[    0.185395] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 249)
[    0.185412] io scheduler noop registered
[    0.185421] io scheduler deadline registered
[    0.185445] io scheduler cfq registered (default)
[    0.186537] tps65217-bl tps65217-bl: no platform data provided
[    0.186564] tps65217-bl: probe of tps65217-bl failed with error -22
[    0.187149] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 4 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
[    0.188596] omap_uart 44e09000.serial: did not get pins for uart0 error: -19
[    0.188863] 44e09000.serial: ttyO0 at MMIO 0x44e09000 (irq = 88) is a OMAP UART0
[    0.916186] console [ttyO0] enabled
[    0.920592] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
[    0.933249] brd: module loaded
[    0.940465] loop: module loaded
[    0.943867] at24 0-0050: 32768 byte 24c256 EEPROM, writable, 1 bytes/write
[    0.951134] at24 1-0054: 32768 byte 24c256 EEPROM, writable, 1 bytes/write
[    0.958390] at24 1-0055: 32768 byte 24c256 EEPROM, writable, 1 bytes/write
[    0.965643] at24 1-0056: 32768 byte 24c256 EEPROM, writable, 1 bytes/write
[    0.972896] at24 1-0057: 32768 byte 24c256 EEPROM, writable, 1 bytes/write
[    0.986788] bone-capemgr bone_capemgr.8: Baseboard: 'A335BNLT,00C0,2314SBB19396'
[    0.994549] bone-capemgr bone_capemgr.8: compatible-baseboard=ti,beaglebone-black
[    1.033252] bone-capemgr bone_capemgr.8: slot #0: No cape found
[    1.070354] bone-capemgr bone_capemgr.8: slot #1: No cape found
[    1.107463] bone-capemgr bone_capemgr.8: slot #2: No cape found
[    1.144572] bone-capemgr bone_capemgr.8: slot #3: No cape found
[    1.150794] bone-capemgr bone_capemgr.8: slot #4: specific override
[    1.157383] bone-capemgr bone_capemgr.8: bone: Using override eeprom data at slot 4
[    1.165404] bone-capemgr bone_capemgr.8: slot #4: 'Bone-LT-eMMC-2G,00A0,Texas Instrument,BB-BONE-EMM'
[    1.175501] bone-capemgr bone_capemgr.8: slot #5: specific override
[    1.182074] bone-capemgr bone_capemgr.8: bone: Using override eeprom data at slot 5
[    1.190084] bone-capemgr bone_capemgr.8: slot #5: 'Bone-Black-HDMI,00A0,Texas Instrument,BB-BONELT-H'
[    1.200072] bone-capemgr bone_capemgr.8: slot #6: specific override
[    1.206646] bone-capemgr bone_capemgr.8: bone: Using override eeprom data at slot 6
[    1.214655] bone-capemgr bone_capemgr.8: slot #6: 'Bone-Black-HDMIN,00A0,Texas Instrument,BB-BONELT-'
[    1.225150] bone-capemgr bone_capemgr.8: initialized OK.
[    1.230761] bone-capemgr bone_capemgr.8: slot #4: Requesting firmware 'cape-bone-2g-emmc1.dtbo' for '
[    1.244334] bone-capemgr bone_capemgr.8: slot #5: Requesting firmware 'cape-boneblack-hdmi-00A0.dtbo'
[    1.259632] OneNAND driver initializing
[    1.264580] usbcore: registered new interface driver asix
[    1.270275] bone-capemgr bone_capemgr.8: slot #4: dtbo 'cape-bone-2g-emmc1.dtbo' loaded; converting e
[    1.280950] bone-capemgr bone_capemgr.8: slot #5: dtbo 'cape-boneblack-hdmi-00A0.dtbo' loaded; convee
[    1.292238] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether
[    1.298410] usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc95xx
[    1.304618] bone-capemgr bone_capemgr.8: slot #4: #2 overlays
[    1.311173] bone-capemgr bone_capemgr.8: slot #5: #4 overlays
[    1.317255] usbcore: registered new interface driver net1080
[    1.323751] bone-capemgr bone_capemgr.8: slot #4: Applied #2 overlays.
[    1.331918] platform 4830e000.fb: alias fck already exists
[    1.337789] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_subset
[    1.345034] bone-capemgr bone_capemgr.8: slot #5: Applied #4 overlays.
[    1.351966] bone-capemgr bone_capemgr.8: slot #6: Requesting firmware 'cape-boneblack-hdmin-00A0.dtb'
[    1.366344] usbcore: registered new interface driver zaurus
[    1.372377] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ncm
[    1.378367] bone-capemgr bone_capemgr.8: slot #6: dtbo 'cape-boneblack-hdmin-00A0.dtbo' loaded; conve
[    1.390257] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
[    1.396220] cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters
[    1.404604] Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
[    1.409932] bone-capemgr bone_capemgr.8: slot #6: BB-BONELT-HDMIN conflict P8.45 (#5:BB-BONELT-HDMI)
[    1.419507] bone-capemgr bone_capemgr.8: slot #6: Failed verification
[    1.426253] bone-capemgr bone_capemgr.8: loader: retrying slot-6 BB-BONELT-HDMIN:00A0 (prio 2)
[    1.435353] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    1.441641] USB Mass Storage support registered.
[    1.446508] bone-capemgr bone_capemgr.8: loader: failed to load slot-6 BB-BONELT-HDMIN:00A0 (prio 2)
[    1.456186] musb-hdrc: version 6.0, ?dma?, otg (peripheral+host)
[    1.462845] musb-hdrc musb-hdrc.0.auto: pdev->id = 0
[    1.468079] musb-hdrc musb-hdrc.0.auto: drivers/usb/musb/musb_dsps.c:468 dsps_musb_init: OK
[    1.476995] musb-hdrc musb-hdrc.0.auto: *** mode=3
[    1.482045] musb-hdrc musb-hdrc.0.auto: *** power=250
[    1.487795] musb-hdrc musb-hdrc.1.auto: pdev->id = 1
[    1.493034] musb-hdrc musb-hdrc.1.auto: drivers/usb/musb/musb_dsps.c:468 dsps_musb_init: OK
[    1.501919] musb-hdrc musb-hdrc.1.auto: *** mode=1
[    1.506953] musb-hdrc musb-hdrc.1.auto: *** power=250
[    1.512253] musb-hdrc musb-hdrc.1.auto: MUSB HDRC host driver
[    1.518501] musb-hdrc musb-hdrc.1.auto: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    1.526865] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.533972] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.541538] usb usb1: Product: MUSB HDRC host driver
[    1.546747] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 3.8.13 musb-hcd
[    1.552408] usb usb1: SerialNumber: musb-hdrc.1.auto
[    1.558263] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.562250] hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    1.567168] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    1.574637] omap_rtc 44e3e000.rtc: rtc core: registered 44e3e000.rtc as rtc0
[    1.582105] 44e3e000.rtc: already running
[    1.586491] i2c /dev entries driver
[    1.591132] pps_ldisc: PPS line discipline registered
[    1.596537] Driver for 1-wire Dallas network protocol.
[    1.603086] omap_wdt: OMAP Watchdog Timer Rev 0x01: initial timeout 60 sec
[    1.610514] cpuidle: using governor ladder
[    1.614813] cpuidle: using governor menu
[    1.619267] omap_hsmmc mmc.4: of_parse_phandle_with_args of 'reset' failed
[    1.626470] omap_hsmmc mmc.4: Failed to get rstctl; not using any
[    1.633138] edma-dma-engine edma-dma-engine.0: allocated channel for 0:25
[    1.640292] edma-dma-engine edma-dma-engine.0: allocated channel for 0:24
[    1.647554] mmc.4 supply vmmc_aux not found, using dummy regulator
[    1.654385] omap_hsmmc mmc.4: pins are not configured from the driver
[    1.687780] gpio-rctrl rstctl.3: gpio_rctrl_request eMMC_RSTn
[    1.693929] omap_hsmmc mmc.10: Got rstctl (gpio:#0 name eMMC_RSTn) label:eMMC_RSTn
[    1.701894] gpio-rctrl rstctl.3: gpio_rctrl_deassert eMMC_RSTn
[    1.708248] edma-dma-engine edma-dma-engine.0: allocated channel for 0:3
[    1.715340] edma-dma-engine edma-dma-engine.0: allocated channel for 0:2
[    1.722730] mmc.10 supply vmmc_aux not found, using dummy regulator
[    1.729380] omap_hsmmc mmc.10: pins are not configured from the driver
[    1.764055] pinctrl-single 44e10800.pinmux: pin 44e10854 already requested by 44e10800.pinmux; canno7
[    1.775714] pinctrl-single 44e10800.pinmux: pin-21 (gpio-leds.7) status -22
[    1.783001] pinctrl-single 44e10800.pinmux: could not request pin 21 on device pinctrl-single
[    1.791943] leds-gpio gpio-leds.7: pins are not configured from the driver
[    1.799923] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[    1.806524] edma-dma-engine edma-dma-engine.0: allocated channel for 0:36
[    1.813706] omap-sham 53100000.sham: hw accel on OMAP rev 4.3
[    1.821133] omap-aes 53500000.aes: OMAP AES hw accel rev: 3.2
[    1.827366] edma-dma-engine edma-dma-engine.0: allocated channel for 0:5
[    1.834506] edma-dma-engine edma-dma-engine.0: allocated channel for 0:6
[    1.842282] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    1.848175] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    1.854982] davinci_evm sound.13:  nxp-hdmi-hifi <-> 48038000.mcasp mapping ok
[    1.864884] TCP: cubic registered
[    1.868434] Initializing XFRM netlink socket
[    1.872940] mmc0: host does not support reading read-only switch. assuming write-enable.
[    1.881434] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    1.886155] NET: Registered protocol family 15
[    1.890934] Key type dns_resolver registered
[    1.895546] VFP support v0.3: [    1.898634] mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address aaaa
implementor 41 architecture 3 part 30 variant c rev 3
[    1.909419] ThumbEE CPU extension supported.
[    1.914461] mmcblk0: mmc0:aaaa SE32G 29.7 GiB 
[    1.919791] Registering SWP/SWPB emulation handler
[    1.925028]  mmcblk0: p1 p2
[    1.929261] registered taskstats version 1
[    1.934626] pinctrl-single 44e10800.pinmux: pin 44e109b0 already requested by mmc.10; cannot claim f2
[    1.945179] pinctrl-single 44e10800.pinmux: pin-108 (hdmi.12) status -22
[    1.952220] pinctrl-single 44e10800.pinmux: could not request pin 108 on device pinctrl-single
[    1.961258] slave hdmi.12: Failed to select default state
[    1.966994] slave: probe of hdmi.12 failed with error -22
[    1.973721] tilcdc 4830e000.fb: No power control GPIO
[    1.979176] tilcdc 4830e000.fb: no encoders/connectors found
[    1.985120] tilcdc 4830e000.fb: failed to initialize mode setting
[    2.041065] davinci_mdio 4a101000.mdio: davinci mdio revision 1.6
[    2.047467] davinci_mdio 4a101000.mdio: detected phy mask fffffffe
[    2.053964] mmc1: unrecognised EXT_CSD revision 7
[    2.058912] mmc1: error -22 whilst initialising MMC card
[    2.065234] libphy: 4a101000.mdio: probed
[    2.069487] davinci_mdio 4a101000.mdio: phy[0]: device 4a101000.mdio:00, driver SMSC LAN8710/LAN8720
[    2.079223] Detected MACID = 64:8c:bb:79:96:36
[    2.083814] cpsw 4a100000.ethernet: NAPI disabled
[    2.090055] omap_rtc 44e3e000.rtc: setting system clock to 2000-01-01 00:10:00 UTC (946685400)
[    2.103917] ALSA device list:
[    2.107061]   #0: TI BeagleBone Black
[    2.111497] RAMDISK: gzip image found at block 0
[    2.417298] F2FS-fs (ram0): Magic Mismatch, valid(0xf2f52010) - read(0x75620072)
[    2.425089] F2FS-fs (ram0): Can't find a valid F2FS filesystem
[    2.435229] List of all partitions:
[    2.438971] b300        31166976 mmcblk0  driver: mmcblk
[    2.444571]   b301         1048576 mmcblk0p1 932b313f-01
[    2.450143]   b302        30117376 mmcblk0p2 932b313f-02
[    2.455719] No filesystem could mount root, tried:  ext3 ext2 ext4 cramfs vfat msdos f2fs
[    2.464354] Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(1,0)
[    2.473034] [<c001051d>] (unwind_backtrace+0x1/0x8c) from [<c0373f21>] (panic+0x55/0x14c)
[    2.481601] [<c0373f21>] (panic+0x55/0x14c) from [<c05ea967>] (mount_block_root+0x13b/0x178)
[    2.490414] [<c05ea967>] (mount_block_root+0x13b/0x178) from [<c05eaad3>] (mount_root+0x8b/0xa8)
[    2.499604] [<c05eaad3>] (mount_root+0x8b/0xa8) from [<c05eabb5>] (prepare_namespace+0xc5/0x118)
[    2.508772] [<c05eabb5>] (prepare_namespace+0xc5/0x118) from [<c0370a27>] (kernel_init+0x7/0x90)
[    2.517953] [<c0370a27>] (kernel_init+0x7/0x90) from [<c000c6fd>] (ret_from_fork+0x11/0x34)

This is the content of my root file system:
    .
├── bin
│   ├── some binaries here -> busybox
├── dev
├── etc
│   └── init.d
│       └── rcS
├── linuxrc -> bin/busybox
├── proc
├── sbin
│   ├── some other binaries -> ../bin/busybox
├── sys
└── usr
    ├── bin
    │   ├── more binaries -> ../../bin/busybox
    └── sbin
        ├── more and more binaries -> ../../bin/busybox

11 directories, 407 files

I want to generate the very minimalist root file system, so I cannot spot what is the key file/directory am I missing ?

"I get this archive by compiling busybox, then gzip the output directory, then use cpio to archive, and finally use mkimage to add the u-boot header." -- could you update your question to include the exact sequence of commands you run in order to generate the image?

I can't say, for sure that yours will work, but the Kernel isn't even managing to recognise it as a filesystem at all.  The problem isn't to do with the content of your root filesystem, you are not getting that far.
That's probobally because uboot thinks it's only 64 bytes large. That doesn't look right at all. Busybox is small, but its not that small.
From your output:
## Loading init Ramdisk from Legacy Image at 88080000 ...                                                                                                                                                          
Image Name:                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Created:      2024-07-29  23:20:31 UTC                                                                                                                                                                          
Image Type:   ARM Linux RAMDisk Image (gzip compressed)                                                                                                                                                         
Data Size:    64 Bytes = 64 Bytes    


uBoot is a bit odd in that it's more of a toolkit than a single program. It really depends on the configuration it was compiled with as to how it behaves.  I don't know where on the BBB you are supposed to put your initramfs image. But you should avoid following generic instructions for uBoot and make sure your instructions are specific for the BBB.
The problem might also be with the way you've used mkimage. It's possible that the header does not contain the right information. IE the header may say initramfs is 64 bytes even though there's a lot more data there.

This is a very good catch. I was using the uboot header with mkimage incorrectly, generating only 64 bytes.

However, even when fixing this, I will have the same issue. I will post the full log now
